# Xpath to select displayed button whenever multiple hidden buttons are also returned

Tags: xpath

I am attempting to select the following Undo button on my web application

[image]

The HTML of the undo button is made up of the following

```
<a href="" style="vertical-align: middle" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-show="true" ng-click="executeUndoCommand(transfer)">Undo</a>
```

The row within the table that contains the Undo button is made up of the following

```
<tr ng-repeat="transfer in completedTransfersSummary track by $id(transfer)">
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle" ng- 
style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}" ng-class=" 
{'highlight' : transfer.transferorBusinessId == CisBusinessID }" 
class="highlight">608445</td>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle" ng- 
style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}" ng-class=" 
{'highlight' : transfer.transfereeBusinessId == CisBusinessID }">608446</td>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle" nowrap="" ng- 
style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">Merger</td>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle" nowrap="" ng- 
 style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">19/07/2018</td>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle" nowrap="" ng- 
 style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">02/01/2018</td>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle" nowrap="" ng- 
 style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">1.00 entitlements @ 
€229.27</td>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle" ng- 
style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">526461</td>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle" ng- 
 style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}">2018</td>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle" ng- 
 style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}"></td>
                    <td style="vertical-align: middle;" ng- 
 show="undoWithdrawRoleAssignedToUser">
                        <div ng-show="transfer.transferorBusinessId == 
CisBusinessID">
                            <a href="" style="vertical-align: middle" 
class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-show="true" ng- 
click="executeUndoCommand(transfer)">Undo</a>
                            <a href="" style="vertical-align: middle" 
class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ng-hide" ng-show="false" ng- 
click="showUndoModal(transfer)">Undo</a>

                            <a href="" style="vertical-align: middle" 
class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-show="true" ng- 
click="executeWithdrawCommand(transfer)">Withdraw</a>
                            <a href="" style="vertical-align: middle" 
class="btn btn-default btn-sm ng-hide" ng-show="false" ng- 
click="showWithdrawModal(transfer)">Withdraw</a>

                            <label style="vertical-align: middle" ng- 
show="false" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}" 
class="ng-hide"></label>
                            <label style="vertical-align: middle" ng- 
show="false" ng-style="transfer.isDisabled &amp;&amp; {color:'#A6A6A6'}" 
class="ng-hide"></label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

I used the following XPath to highlight the Undo button on the screen

```
("//tr[td='Merger']//a[@ng-click='executeUndoCommand(transfer)']")
```

It reuturns the button I requre but also returns 3 hidden buttons, for the test I am running I need to only select the displayed button. The button I requre is the 4th on the list below

```
 $x("//tr[td='Merger']//a[@ng-click='executeUndoCommand(transfer)']")
(4) [a.btn.btn-primary.btn-sm.ng-hide, a.btn.btn-primary.btn-sm.ng-hide, 
a.btn.btn-primary.btn-sm.ng-hide, a.btn.btn-primary.btn-sm]
0
:
a.btn.btn-primary.btn-sm.ng-hide
1
:
a.btn.btn-primary.btn-sm.ng-hide
2
:
a.btn.btn-primary.btn-sm.ng-hide
3
:
a.btn.btn-primary.btn-sm
length
:
4
```

I changed the xpath to the following to attempt to select the displayed button but these are not working

```
$x("//tr[td='Merger']//a[@ng-click='executeUndoCommand(transfer)' and 
@class='btn btn-default btn-sm']")

$x("//tr[td='Merger']//a[@ng-click='executeUndoCommand(transfer)']//a[@ng- 
show='true']")
```

Can anybody suggest a way to hightlight the button I require?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something similar to  this

```
//a[text()='Undo' and not(contains(@class,'hide'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would work for you //tr[td='Merger']//a[@ng-click='executeUndoCommand(transfer)'][@class='btn btn-default btn-sm']

Comment: Hi, unfortuantely no nothing is returned when using that XPath.

Comment: May i know what language you are using to develop your script @AlpineF30

Comment: Hi there, I am using C#

Answer (score 0):

Since the A link buttons contain the attributes of either ng-show="true" or ng-show="false", this XPATH selector should work:

//a[text()='Undo' and @ng-show="true"]